# How can subwavelength grating provides mometum require to excite SPP?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, electromagnetic-radiation, plasmon

Subwavelength grating shows no diffraction orders of course except 0th order, then how will it get required momentum to match with Surface plasmon excitation? is it any role of evanescent wave?

Comment: I think this is the same question as https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/88800/exciting-surface-plasmon-polaritons-with-grating-coupling

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exciting Surface Plasmon-Polaritons with Grating Coupling](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/88800/exciting-surface-plasmon-polaritons-with-grating-coupling)

Comment: here you have diffraction orders that vg= m . wavelength/ period can add into in plane wave and  make resonance with SPP, but subwavelength grating shows no diffraction order.

Comment: I see, removed the close vote.